# Click at specified client area

Tags: c#, click, client, mouse, sendmessage

`Click` doesn't work - I don't know why and can't find a solution :(

ie. `Click(150,215)` should move mouse to the client area and click there.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ScreenToClient(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);

    [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    static void MouseMove(int x, int y)
    {
        Point p = new Point(x * -1, y * -1);
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, ref p);
        p = new Point(p.X * -1, p.Y * -1);
        SetCursorPos(p.X, p.Y);
    }

    static void Click(int x, int y)
    {
        MouseMove(x, y);
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x1, new IntPtr(y * 0x10000 + x));
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)0x1, new IntPtr(y * 0x10000 + x));
    }
```

**Edit:**
***Following methods are working, but are "more advanced" I would say.***

Of course I can use `mouse_event` for that, but I would like to see a solution for SendMessage()...

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    const int LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002;
    const int LEFTUP = 0x00000004;

    static void Click(int x, int y)
    {
        MouseMove(x, y);
        mouse_event((int)(LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event((int)(LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

After a while I found another method with `MouseInput` by `SendInput`, but it's very long :P

can it be shrinked?

```
        [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MouseInputData mi;
    }
    struct MouseInputData
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        public SendInputEventType type;
        public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
    }
    enum SendInputEventType : int
    {
        InputMouse,
    }

    static void Click(int x, int y)
    {
        INPUT mouseInput = new INPUT();
        mouseInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dx = x;
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dy = y;
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.mouseData = 0;

        MouseMove(x, y);
        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not investigated the exact issue you describe, I would recommend you take a look at [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932376.aspx) and [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) which are Windows API calls designed to do what you describe.

`mouse_event` is the older version of the call, `SendInput` is newer and supersedes `mouse_input` by supporting multiple input events. Both methods are available on P/Invoke.net at the URL's listed below:

- `mouse_event`: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html
- `SendInput`: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html

Comment: Thanks, I already have the mouse_event method. Do you think `SendInput` is better (performance, speed) than simple `SendMessage` ?

Comment: Look at my edit please and tell me if it can be shrinked somehow :)

Comment: Sending `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to any window you don't own seems like it would be prone to error.  I cannot find any actual documentation suggesting use of `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` being used that way, and I do know `mouse_event` and `SendInput` are the supported ways.  If you are concerned about the performance of such a call, you would have to benchmark them.  Although `SendInput` is verbose, most of it is P/Invoke signatures.

Comment: Okay, anyway I found two another methods to solve this problem :)